# Balun single-ended 50 Ω to LVDS 100 Ω conversion

Tags: pcb, transformer, differential, lvds, balun

I have an LVDS differential 100 Ω signal which I want to convert to a single-ended 50 Ω signal. I want to use a BALUN for this conversion.

What kind of BALUN should I use here?

[Some](https://www.minicircuits.com/WebStore/dashboard.html?model=ADT1-1WT%2B) BALUNs have a 1:1 conversion ratio.
[Some](https://www.minicircuits.com/WebStore/dashboard.html?model=ADT2-1T%2B) have  2:1 impedance conversion ratio.

Comment: Since your impedance ratio is 2:1 why do you even have to ask the question?

Comment: The 100OHM LVDS signal connects to two terminals of the BALUN. If we consider the differential signal as two 50 OHM signals than in my reasoning I should use a 1:1 balun. However in some designs I have seen a 2:1 balun used as well. I am looking for a more clear answer.

Comment: Also note that your selection of balun will be influenced by the driving frequency of the LVDS.  Most often I have seen them made to work at 400Hz or 50/60 Hz  some modern smaller units may be higher.  The magnetics are not all the same.

Comment: Voting to close: please provide more information about the application. What are the transmitter (known: LVDS) and receiver (unknown)? Bandwidth? Distance, line losses, BER, or other signal level or SNR related concerns? If the question is a matter of resolving a confusion, please provide examples, background information, references, etc. illustrating your concerns.

Answer (score 1):

A 100 ohm diff signal is essentially 2 x 50 ohm single ended signals (I know that's a very same analogy).

In the past ive  connected  one end of the differential signal to the receiver with a 50R series resistor, and the other end terminate with 100R to GND.